# How can I restrict TFS releases by environment?

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a TFS build server with CI builds and releases set up.  We're looking to only allow a specific team to perform a deployment to production.  I'd like to not allow people to select the production environment under deploy.  Is that possible, or do I have to restrict it by adding an approver?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use Release Management installed or the web-based version in TFS 2015 Update 2 and above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Environment security can only control the permissions below, you can't set Create releases permission under Environment:

- Administer release permissions
- Delete release environment
- Edit release environment
- Manage deployments
- Manage release approvers

[image]

So you need to assign pre-deployment approvers under Environment to restrict TFS releases for the production environment .

Comment: you should briefly touch on having a separate Agent Pool to isolate production access.